Premiere pro adds audio pop at beginning of slowed down tracks
In Premiere Pro, I sometimes slow down an Interview to 90% of original speed, in order to make a very-fast speaking person more easy to follow.
So, I adjust clip speed/duration, set it at 90% and select 'maintain audio pitch', as of the below screenshot. However, at each cut, there's an audible 'pop' whenever the interviewee starts speaking. It's impossible to eliminate with audio transitions or by fading in the audio using key frames.

The pop persists even in exports.
The only workaround I have found is toI slow down the audio in Audition (or a different audio processor) and re-import it into premiere. However, this adds a lot of work, especially if there are many cuts.
Is there any way to avoid the audio pops in premiere pro ?
I have a suspect that it's a bug in premiere, as slowing down the audio also adds a sort of "reverb" effect, so probably the algorithm behind such function is not really "clean".

I've never had this happen to me before. One possible reason: maybe there is a DC-offset on your audio recording? This can sometimes cause clicks as the audio clip quickly transitions from "digital silence" to whatever the offset level is on the recording. Slowing these clicks down would make them sound like pops. DC offset should be visible in the waveform, if you open the clips in Audition.
This image isn't from Audition, but it demonstrates what DC offset looks like:

Audition has a repair DC offset function I think. Process your audio files with that, then try your slowdowns & transitions etc in Premiere.

Thank you for this, but I use audio straight out of my GH5, and it records in LPCM, with a noticeable noise floor.  I actually think it's a bug in premiere: slowing down the audio also adds a sort of "reverb" effect, so probably the algorithm which is used is not really "clean".
